# Vowpal Wabbit Readable Model Doesnt Have weights

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I wanted to do lasso regression with Vowpal Wabbit. So, I used this command line

```
vw --save_resume --readable_model ob/e/nsefut/VW_testing/BuyModel.VWM -d ob/e/nsefut/VW_testing/VWsell.VWF --quiet --predictions ob/e/nsefut/VW_testing/predict.VW --loss_function logistic --noconstant --l1 0.001
```

The readable file shows no weights of the features that I used. But when I skip the param --l1 then it shows the weights properly.Plus when I dont give --l1 param, it came up with weights like this..

- 1:-0.437898 994842.000000 1.000000
- 33340:-0.176359 201942.265625 1.006310
- 59044:-0.152967 201843.875000 1.002754
- 63438:-0.187405 202149.140625 1.015530
- 124204:-0.159398 201741.187500 1.002742
- 166130:-0.185312 201754.421875 1.013330

Which suggest that all the weights are negative. But all my features are +ve valued. Hence my linear combination of features would be negative for all observation resulting prediction -ve for all observation. But I am seeing both +ve and -ve as predicted label.

Three questions

1. Whether my command line is correct for lasso regression.
2. What will enable me to see the weights.
3. What is it that making me not understand the all negative weights incident

Comment: Logistic loss works with classes labeled +/-1. This part of line: 63438:-0.187405 is a feature hash and it's coefficient. In linear model y = a*x + c the negative thing will be an `a`. And value of feature you passed to VW is x. So if all your coefficients are negative than I guess this model predicts class -1 for any known features. And I suspect --l1 regularizes out all features. Are you sure your dataset is correctly labeled? Could you try --l1 with smaller value?

Comment: Ad1) it looks OK Ad2) In online learning (which is the default in VW) you regularize each example, so the lambdas are generally much lower than in batch learning. E.g. if an optimal batch `--l1` is 1 and you have 1 million examples, try `--l1=1e-6` in online learning. Ad3) Are you sure **all** weights are negative? General: what version of VW do you have? Can you reproduce the strange behavior on smaller data? Can you share the smaller data, so others can replicate the experiment?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation of using lower --l1 param. The whole time I was wondering why in batch learning I used to give it as 1.0 and why people giving all l1 values lower than atleast 1e-4 . I tried with lower l1, but the problem is even when the predictions look ok ( as they are not all same valued, so there must be a feature which was selected ), still there is no weight stored in the model file.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with ``$ vowpalwabbit/vw ./test/train-sets/rcv1_small.dat --l1 1e-6 --readable_model model.txt --save_resume --predictions pred.txt --loss_function logistic --noconstant --quiet && tail model.txt `` and up-to-date vw. Features must be regularized out. I suspect your predictions look ok only at begin of predictions file. And they are all the same at its end. VW outputs predictions while adjusting feature coefficients, but saves readable model at very end when all features coefficients converged to 0.

Comment: Does your statement "VW outputs predictions while adjusting feature coefficients, but saves readable model at very end when all features coefficients converged to 0" necessarily mean that VW doesnt use 23rd observation to predict for 3rd observation?

Comment: It doesn't. It implements online learning - "learn and forget". It stores only coefs. Thus it can process enormous amount of data. So VW uses knowledge it got from examples already seen to predict current observation. Thus it knows nothing about 23rd when predicts 3rd - it seen only first two so far. Thus predictions at very beginning will be naive. You may train it on whole dataset and save model file with `-f model.file`. Then launch it again on same dataset in test-only mode with `-i model.file -t`. In this case it applies knowledge it got from all observations. But you'll overfit model!

Comment: Very much appreciated @truf .. I got my answers thanks to you :)